# Gson Postgres Timestamp serialization

Tags: java, android, postgresql, gson

the problem is in the Postegres timestamp serialization using GSON,

```
private static final GsonBuilder GSON_BASE = Converters
        .registerAll(new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping())
        .registerTypeAdapter(InfoTransfer.class, new InfoTransfer.Adapter())
        .setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL) //Line added but it seems work for MySQL DB Timestamp
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .create();
.
//inner class in InfoTransfer 
public static class Adapter implements JsonSerializer<InfoTransfer>{

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(InfoTransfer src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

        Gson gson= new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject= (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(src);

        return new JsonPrimitive(jsonObject.getAsString());
    }
}
.
.
.
Log.d("Result",GSON_BASE.toJson(data));
```

expected result :

```
"created_at": "2016-10-13 18:18:51.64208+01"
```

result :

```
\"created_at\": \"\\u0000\\u0001\\ufffdM\\u0015q\\ufffd}\"
```

so any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format can be set as follows:-

```
setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX")
```

**Example:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jsonString = "{\"customorId\":\"506\",\"joiningDate\":\"2016-10-26 19:49:17.290671+01\"}";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX") 
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();


        //Deserialize
        Customer customer = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Customer.class);
        System.out.println(customer.toString());

        //Serialize
        Customer customerSerialize = new Customer();
        customerSerialize.setCustomorId("123");
        customerSerialize.setJoiningDate(new Date());

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(customerSerialize));


    }
```

**Customer class:-**

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1100012615187080642L;

    private String customorId;

    private Date joiningDate;

}
```

**Sample output:-**

```
Customer [customorId=506, joiningDate=Wed Oct 26 19:54:07 BST 2016]
{
  "customorId": "123",
  "joiningDate": "2016-10-26 20:23:37.000811+01"
}
```

Comment: thank you bro :), this solution works if you got the date in string format ^^, but in my case we wanted to serialize the Postgres timestamp, so we used to update the web service to send it in String format. I will post the solution, it is the same like yours

Comment: Ok. The solution was based on the expected result of OP. Also, I have verified it with NOW() in postgres (now() is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)